# Make maximized windows in Win 10 automatically take new desktop?

Tags: windows-10, macos

I much prefer the way maximize works on macOS, in which every maximized window becomes its own Desktop.

Is it possible to make it so every maximized window automatically becomes its own desktop in Windows 10?